# Getting Default value N'no' is not supported for VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT 'no'

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2000, data-migration

I'm using the MySQL Workbench 6.0 tool to migrating data from a MS SQL Server 2000 database to a MySQL 5.6 database and many of the create table constructs are giving the error "Default value N'no' is not supported" on columns that allow null, but define a default value.  Here is some example code where the complaint is on the definition of the distribution column definition.

The Table construct looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dbo`.`_tbl_access` (
`distribution` VARCHAR(3) NULL DEFAULT 'no',
`email` VARCHAR(100) NULL)
```

The idea is that you can store NULL, but have the default be 'no'. Is this a known problem to allow NULL, but to store a value of 'no' as default?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the MySLQ 5.6 documentation, you can't use your own default value on a column which can take NULL as a value:

> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

[11.5. Data Type Default Values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html)

If you want exactly the same behavior, you can use custom triggers. You may also consider redesigning the database, e.g. to ask yourself if a record should exist in the '_tbl_access' table if the answer for the 'distribution' field is undefined (NULL).